# CakePHP authorization redirects based on role

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to think of a simple way to redirect a user based on their role, and set access based on this.

For example, if a user is suspended, I change their role to 'suspended'. When that user logs in or accesses any page, I would like it to redirect to a page with information that describes what happened and how to become unsuspended. If they try to access any other controller/action, I would like it to again redirect to that "suspended" page.

Here's what I have in my AppController

```
 public function isAuthorized($user=null) {
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can I add something like this, but have a custom redirect and custom flash message **only** for the suspended scenario?

```
public function isAuthorized($user=null) {

    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }
    elseif(isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'suspended'){
                 return false; //but somehow redirect to that 'suspended' page with flash message
     }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Use the redirect function to handle the redirect. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: Is there something special I have to do? I tried just simply putting $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'suspended)); but it didn't work

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your session.
 Create flash session `$this->Session->write('message','Youre message')` before you redirect. Then call session in the page redirected `if(isset($this->Session->read('message'))`. Just don't forget to delete session.

Comment: Flash messages are more likely (and standard) for this kind of messages.