# Updating user role without logging out in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I had a question regarding roles of users and redirects based on it, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499604/cakephp-authorization-redirects-based-on-role). Well, now I'm having a different issue but stemming from that.

When a user is suspended, their role upon logging is 'suspended'. If the user fills out a form their suspension can be lifted, however, their role is still set to 'suspended'. How can I change the user role from 'suspended' to 'reg_user' or something else?

I tried doing the following

```
if(AuthComponent::user('role') == 'suspended'){
    $this->User->id = AuthComponent::user('id');
    $this->User->saveField('role', 'reg_user'); //udate their role in the database
    $this->set('role', 'reg_user');  //now set their role to reg_user
 }
```

However, that user's role is still set to 'suspended' until they log out and back in. I'd prefer to not have to do that, but if that's the only way then I suppose that'll have to do.

Comment: Have you tried looking in `$_SESSION` ? Maybe the user's role is defined there too.

Comment: @Mike yep, that was it. Had to use $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['role'] = 'reg_user'; Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `$this->controller->Session->write('Auth', $this->controller->User->read(null, $this->controller->Auth->User('id')));` is the CakePHP solution to overwrite the user data

Answer (score 0):

i think this will workout

```
$this->$User->role='reg_user';
$this->$User->save();
```